# How to use CFPreferencesSetAppValue with a container?

Tags: cocoa, pyobjc, cfpreferences

#### OS X + Excel 2016

Us non-english speakers want our computer localized, but we want to use Excel english formulas. To do this we need to have Excel speaking another language, thus setting AppleLanguages GlobalPreference for an app to override the system settings.

It’s easier to learn and talk about =SUM() than =SOMME() or =NPV() than =VAN()

#### Idea

To make this easier for my user, I'm writing an Python+Cocoa application that will basically ask the user for the language he/she wants and store it in the preference file.

In CLI, to set (only) Excel to English, run:

```
 $ defaults write com.microsoft.Excel AppleLanguages "('en’)”
```

#### My Issue

I run :

```
newLanguageCode = ['zh-CN']
CoreFoundation.CFPreferencesSetAppValue('AppleLanguages', newLanguageCode, 'com.microsoft.Excel')
```

The problem is that it writes to ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.plist instead of ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.plist

How can I tell CFPreferencesSetAppValue to write to the Container instead of home ?

#### Appendices

```
minidefrancois:Library francois$ defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.plist 
{
    AppleLanguages =     (
        "zh-CN"
    );
}


minidefrancois:Library francois$ defaults read -app /Applications/Microsoft\ Excel.app/
{
    AppExitGraceful = 0;
    AppleLanguages =     (
        en
    );
    ExceptionEnum = 0;
    NSRecentDocumentsLimit = 0;
    "NSWindow Frame FileUIWindowFrameAutoSaveName" = "276 322 1046 626 0 0 1680 1027 ";
    OCModelLanguage = "fr-FR";
    OCModelVersion = "0.838";
    OUIWhatsNewLastShownLink = 624954;
    SendAllTelemetryEnabled = 1;
    SessionBuildNumber = 151008;
    SessionId = "55FDAD65-D013-4184-A5A5-CBF747DC563D";
    SessionStartTime = "10/21/2015 10:49:43.997";
    SessionVersion = "15.15";
    TemplateDownload = 1;
    kFileUIDefaultTabID = 1;
    kOUIRibbonDefaultCollapse = 0;
    kSubUIAppCompletedFirstRunSetup1507 = 1;
}


minidefrancois:Library francois$ defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.plist
{
    AppExitGraceful = 0;
    AppleLanguages =     (
        en
    );
    ExceptionEnum = 0;
    NSRecentDocumentsLimit = 0;
    "NSWindow Frame FileUIWindowFrameAutoSaveName" = "276 322 1046 626 0 0 1680 1027 ";
    OCModelLanguage = "fr-FR";
    OCModelVersion = "0.838";
    OUIWhatsNewLastShownLink = 624954;
    SendAllTelemetryEnabled = 1;
    SessionBuildNumber = 151008;
    SessionId = "55FDAD65-D013-4184-A5A5-CBF747DC563D";
    SessionStartTime = "10/21/2015 10:49:43.997";
    SessionVersion = "15.15";
    TemplateDownload = 1;
    kFileUIDefaultTabID = 1;
    kOUIRibbonDefaultCollapse = 0;
    kSubUIAppCompletedFirstRunSetup1507 = 1;
}
minidefrancois:Library francois$
```

Comment: Interestingly, I have the opposite problem. Calling CFPreferencesSetAppValue on com.apple.screenshot saves to ../Containers/... where as I want to edit the one in ~/Library/Preferences

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas Burgin and Greg Neagle:

needs to set app ID to :

```
NSHomeDirectory() + "/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel"
```

I pushed it to https://github.com/ftiff/Office8n

Here’s the relevant code:

```
homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory()
appName = homeDirectory + "/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel”
propertyName = ‘AppleLanguages’ (unused here, will later)
_dropDown = objc.IBOutlet()

   def getPreference(self, appName, propertyName, _dropDown):
       result = CoreFoundation.CFPreferencesCopyAppValue('AppleLanguages', appName)
       # if it's an array, return only first value
       if isinstance(result, NSArray):
           result = result[0]
       language = self.codeToLanguage.get(result, "English")
       _dropDown.selectItemWithTitle_(language)
       return result

_label = @objc.IBAction

   def savePreference(self, propertyName, _value, appName, _label):
       propertyValue = []
       propertyValue.append(_value)
       CoreFoundation.CFPreferencesSetAppValue(propertyName, propertyValue, appName)
       CoreFoundation.CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(appName)
       NSLog("{appName}: {propertyName} = {propertyValue}".format(
                                                                  appName=appName,
                                                                  propertyName=propertyName,
                                                                  propertyValue=propertyValue
                                                                  ))
       _label.setStringValue_("Set to: " + self.codeToLanguage.get(propertyValue[0], "None"))
```